# how do I style this "input" like this "a" tag?

Tags: css

[image]

(The "input" is on the left and the "a" tag is on the right)

I need to style the "input" tag exactly like the "a" tag. I am just talking about the box surrounding it. Also, I can only use the "input" tag because I need to get data from this button

```
a,input {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding: 3px; 
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Please share your code here. We can't help without it.

Comment: Have you tried this: <button><a href="https://google.com">SAVE</a></button>

Comment: @UlquiorraSchiffer [you can't](https://caninclude.glitch.me/caninclude?child=a&parent=button) add a alink inside a button

Answer (score 0):

*Input* and *a* elements have different native style, you can reset the style and apply a mutual class.

For position you can use align-items: stretch or align-items: center from flexbox

For exemple :

```
<div class="inner">
  <input type="text" value="foo" />
  <a href="#"> bar </a>
</div>


.inner {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  height: 140px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.inner input, 
.inner a {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 12px;
  border: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

You can also replace .inner input, .inner a by .yourClass
and add class="yourClass" on input and a DOM element

Comment: what exactly do you mean by resetting the style and applying a mutual class?

Comment: He means use `all: revert;` for your button to remove default styles and add the same class for `a` and `button` as well.

Comment: Yes ! Nice all: revert

Answer (score 0):

Here I have provided a css attributes for the class `inner` and also added a style for the elements input and a.

```css
.inner {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  height: 140px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.inner input {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius:5px;
  margin: 12px;
  border: 0;
  width:45px;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

 
.inner a {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius:5px;
  border: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
  <input type="text" value="save" />
  <a href="#"> cancel </a>
</div>
```